# route a PUT request without a third party routing library

Tags: go

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi5A3cK1LNA) Youtube video (at around 15:29) of a Golang talk by Blake Mizerany, he talks about how to build a router without using a third party package, covering in detail how to construct a route that has a variable component, such as an id. This is the handler that he uses, with the first line showing how to get the variable component of the route (i.e. the key)

```
func productHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    key := r.URL.Path[len("/products/":]
    switch r.Method{
    case "GET":
      //do stuff
    case "POST"
      //do stuff
    default:
       http.Error(w, "method not allowed", 405)
    }
}
```

It's not clear from his presentation though what his actual route looks like.

I'm trying to build a route that handles a put request with an id. When I click an element on my page, it sends a put request to this route

```
http://localhost:8080/products/1433255183951
```

I have a route like this

```
   http.HandleFunc("/products/{id}", doSomethingWithProduct){

   }
```

and of course have the func

```
func doSomethingWithProduct(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request{
     key := req.URL.Path[len("/products/"):]

     log.Println(key, "is this logging?? nope")

}
```

Problem. Even though I have that route set up, and the handler, when I click the element I got a 404 not found, and there's no indication that my function was called (i.e. it's not logging)

Question: How do I create a custom route/func that handles a PUT request to

```
http://localhost:8080/products/1433255183951
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http.HandleFunc` does not handle the "capture groups" like you're trying to do with `{id}`.

`http.HandleFunc("/products/", handler)` will match all routes that begin with this pattern. You have to parse the rest of it yourself.

See [ServeMux](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux).

> ServeMux is an HTTP request multiplexer. It matches the URL of each incoming request against a list of registered patterns and calls the handler for the pattern that most closely matches the URL.
>
> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash). Longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for paths beginning "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree.
>
> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".
>
> Patterns may optionally begin with a host name, restricting matches to URLs on that host only. Host-specific patterns take precedence over general patterns, so that a handler might register for the two patterns "/codesearch" and "codesearch.google.com/" without also taking over requests for "http://www.google.com/".
>
> ServeMux also takes care of sanitizing the URL request path, redirecting any request containing . or .. elements to an equivalent .- and ..-free URL.

Comment: according to SO, you and JimB both responded "5 mins ago". I don't know whose answer to accept so I'll toss a coin. I voted both of you up, however.

Answer (score 3):

`HandleFunc` doesn't know what to do with `{id}`. Give it a specific path it can match:

```
http.HandleFunc("/products/", doSomethingWithProduct)
```

Comment: you both responded "5 mins ago". I don't know whose answer to accept so I'll toss a coin. I voted both of you up, however.

Answer (score 3):

The builtin HTTP router doesn't do anything fancy like binding parameters; however, you can specify entire prefixes to associate with a handler.  See the documentation for [`http.ServeMux`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux).

Try something like this:

```
func main() {
  productsPrefix := "/products/"
  http.HandleFunc(productsPrefix, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if (r.Method == "PUT") && (strings.Index(r.URL.Path, productsPrefix) == 0) {
      productId := r.URL.Path[len(productsPrefix):]
      fmt.Printf("OK: %s %s productId=%s\n", r.Method, r.URL.Path, productId)
    }
  })

  log.Print("Listening on localhost:8080")
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

For example:

```
$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:8080/products/1234
# => OK: PUT /products/1234 productId=1234
```